# Why does an OpenCL project fail when tries to use GPU?

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I am trying to execute OpenCL projects (in C and C++), and when I make the project with the Makefile and I execute it, failing at the command clCreateContextFromType() in the C++ host after compiling the OpenCL kernel.

I am using the following OpenCL benchmark: http://rodinia.cs.virginia.edu/doku.php

Specifically the project I am trying to execute is called "backprop".

The OS where I am doing this is an Ubuntu 18.04 in a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox), I think this is the problem why the OS does not detect the GPU but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is useless to run OpenCL on virtual machine.

Comment: because the GPU is not accessible in the VM. You could try making the GPU visible in the VM by "pci passthrough" (not always possible).

Comment: @mogu I have tried what you said and I have managed to configure the VM to use the Nvidia GPU following this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/779070/use-nvidia-gpu-from-virtualbox).



I can see in the Task Manager that when I use the VM, theoretically it use the Nvidia GPU instead of the CPU integrated GPU, but then in the VM when I try to execute an OpenCL program it does not detect the GPU and stills give me an error.

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález what's described there isn't a pcie passthrough. It's merely a 3D acceleration, IOW it provides some special guest drivers that pass DirectX/OpenGL calls to the host machine. This could in theory work if they had the same thing with OpenCL, but that doesn't exist AFAIK.

Comment: "pcie passthrough" is when your GPU "disappears" from the host machine, and "appears" in the guest. You install the official GPU drivers in the guest, etc. This is only possible with certain hardware support, and with OS support. On linux (host) it worked for a while, for windows i only found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/64r7ul/it_looks_like_windows_10_creators_update_might/